# Subscribe to the Avalonia window events on Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am trying to subscribe to the Avalonia window events using the `libX11` library (Ubuntu 20.04).

I used the `XNextEvent` method, but it hangs.
Also, I added a mask before with the `XSelectInput` method with no success.

The goal is to intersept all the Avalonia window messages using the `libX11` library.

My code snippet:

```cs
[DllImport("libX11.so.6")]
private static extern int XNextEvent(IntPtr display, ref XEvent xevent);

[DllImport("libX11.so.6")]
private static extern int XSelectInput(IntPtr display, IntPtr window, EventMask event_mask);

[DllImport("libX11.so.6")]
private static extern IntPtr XOpenDisplay(IntPtr display);

enum XEventName
{
    KeyPress = 2,
    ButtonPress = 4,
    Expose = 12
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct XEvent
{
    public int type;
    public IntPtr serial;
    public int send_event;
    public IntPtr display;
    public IntPtr window;
}

enum EventMask
{
    KeyPress = 1 << 0,
    ButtonPress = 1 << 2,
    Exposure = 1 << 15
}


 IntPtr display = XOpenDisplay(IntPtr.Zero);
 int result = XSelectInput(display, avaloniaWindow.Handle,
                           EventMask.KeyPress
                           | EventMask.ButtonPress
                           | EventMask.Exposure);

 while (true)
 {
     XEvent xevent = new();
     XNextEvent(display, ref xevent);

     switch ((XEventName)xevent.type)
     {
         case XEventName.KeyPress:
             Debug.WriteLine("KeyPress");
             break;
         case XEventName.ButtonPress:
             Debug.WriteLine("ButtonPress");
             break;
         case XEventName.Expose:
             Debug.WriteLine("Expose");
             break;
         default:
             Debug.WriteLine("Unknown");
             break;
     }
 }
```